# How to split a .rtf file into multiple files based on date line?

Tags: bash, awk, split

I have a rich text document (.rtf) that has notes separated by dates. It follows the format below:

> **2021-4-6**
>
> Some notes
>
> Hyperlink
>
> More text
>
> **2021-4-5**
>
> Notes notes notes

I'd like to split the document so that there is a different file for each date with the corresponding notes saved and the date as the file name. The split command seemed close to what i wanted but it doesn't seem to be able to account for the variable amount of text and lines for each day. Would a bash script work for this? I'm new to this so forgive me if the answer is obvious. Edit: the document contains some leading spaces and blank lines.

An example input file:

> 2020-11-15
>
> How to properly use a NanoVNA V2 Vector Network Analyzer (Tutorial) -
> YouTube -  VNA NanoVNA
>
> Impedence matching an antenna Reflection VNA vs
> Spectrum Analyzer? Usually impedence of 50 ohms VSWR Meter SWR -
> Standing Wave Ratio SWR = 1 means there is no reflected power
>
> 2020-11-11
>
> Superheterodyne receiver - Wikipedia - A superheterodyne receiver,
> often shortened to superhet, is a type of radio receiver that
> uses frequency mixing to convert a received signal to a
> fixed intermediate frequency (IF) which can be more conveniently
> processed than the original carrier frequency. Protected Cell
> Unprotected Cell Logic Gates from Transistors: Transistors and Boolean
> Logic - YouTube -

Would be split into two files:

2020-11-15.rtf

> 2020-11-15
>
> How to properly use a NanoVNA V2 Vector Network Analyzer (Tutorial) -
> YouTube -  VNA NanoVNA
>
> Impedence matching an antenna Reflection VNA vs
> Spectrum Analyzer? Usually impedence of 50 ohms VSWR Meter SWR -
> Standing Wave Ratio SWR = 1 means there is no reflected power

2020-11-11.rtf

> 2020-11-11
>
> Superheterodyne receiver - Wikipedia - A superheterodyne receiver,
> often shortened to superhet, is a type of radio receiver that
> uses frequency mixing to convert a received signal to a
> fixed intermediate frequency (IF) which can be more conveniently
> processed than the original carrier frequency. Protected Cell
> Unprotected Cell Logic Gates from Transistors: Transistors and Boolean
> Logic - YouTube -

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add more clear samples of input and expected output(along with your tried code) in your question, thank you.

Comment: The file has spaces/leading and blank lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}$/ {close(f); f=$0".rtf"} f{print > f}' file
    
==> 2020-11-11.rtf <==
2020-11-11

Superheterodyne receiver - Wikipedia - A superheterodyne receiver, often shortened to superhet, is a type of radio receiver that uses frequency mixing to convert a received signal to a fixed intermediate frequency (IF) which can be more conveniently processed than the original carrier frequency. Protected Cell Unprotected Cell Logic Gates from Transistors: Transistors and Boolean Logic - YouTube -

==> 2020-11-15.rtf <==
2020-11-15

How to properly use a NanoVNA V2 Vector Network Analyzer (Tutorial) - YouTube - VNA NanoVNA

Impedence matching an antenna Reflection VNA vs Spectrum Analyzer? Usually impedence of 50 ohms VSWR Meter SWR - Standing Wave Ratio SWR = 1 means there is no reflected power
```